# how to get the id of the treeview items when I have only parent's parent text

Tags: php, mysql, sql, treeview

My question has a bit complicated. But I will explain detail carefully in below.

First of all. I have three database table which is company,project and phase. When I running sql:

> SELECT company.ID AS companyID, company.Name AS companyName, project.ID AS projectID, project.Name AS projectName,phase.ID AS phaseID, phase.Name AS phaseName FROM company left join project ON project.CompanyID = company.ID left join phase ON phase.ProjectID = project.ID WHERE company.Name = 'Company2' Order By project.ID

I can get the results at below picture. 
[image]

But now I had added a new database table which is treeview_items at below picture.[image]

I wish to let treeview_items table to join the table company, table project and table phase above with using phase.Name = treeview_items.text WHERE company.Name=Company2

Below is the result I wish to get.[image]

I have tried a lot of methods but also can't reach the result I want. Anyone know how to solve this problem please help me. Thanks a lot!!!

SS for sujivasagam[image]

Completely table of treeview_items

[image]

CREATE TABLE treeview_items (  id int(11) NOT NULL,  text varchar(200) NOT NULL, parent_id varchar(200) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO treeview_items (id, text, parent_id) VALUES (1, 'Select All', '0'), (5, 'Company1', '1'), (7, 'Company2', '1'), (9, 'Project11', '5'), (10, 'Project23', '7'), (12, 'Project4', '7'), (14, 'Project5', '7'), (16, 'ProjectTest1', '7'), (24, 'Phase1', '9'), (25, 'Phase2', '9'), (26, 'Phase3', '9'), (27, 'Phase4', '9'), (29, 'PhaseTest7', '9'), (30, 'phase23', '10'), (31, 'Phase1', '12'), (32, 'PhaseTest6', '14'), (33, 'PhaseTest5', '16'), (34, 'PhaseTest4', '16'), (56, 'CompanyTest1', '1'), (63, 'ProjectTest7', '56'), (64, 'PhaseTest3', '63'), (65, 'Phase1', '10'), (68, 'PhaseTest2', '63'), (69, 'PhaseTest1', '63'), (70, 'Phase2', '10'), (73, 'PhaseTest2', '16');

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT company.ID AS companyID, company.Name AS companyName, project.ID AS projectID, project.Name AS projectName,phase.ID AS phaseID, phase.Name AS phaseName, tv.id as treeview_items_id FROM company left join project ON project.CompanyID = company.ID left join phase ON phase.ProjectID = project.ID left join treeview_items tv on(tv.text = phase.Name) WHERE company.Name = 'Company2' group by phaseID Order By project.ID
```

Comment: Sorry, it get the wrong result for column treeview_items_id. And the result od the treeview_items_id is not in my table treeview_items.

Comment: send me the screenshot of the result you got

Comment: I add the ss at above. I also provided a completely treeview_items at above

Comment: I had use the in method before but it occurs duplicate record because there are two same text in the treeview_items when is Phase1

Comment: Can u say the exact thing clearly. or else give the table in sql format. It is too embaracing to create each table and add each and every row to give you the solution

Comment: do you have email.? I can export my table and send it to you

Comment: Nope. Just give the treeview_items table alone

Comment: I had add the sql for table treeview_items at above

Comment: Are you looking for the result of this query?
SELECT company.ID AS companyID, company.Name AS companyName, project.ID AS projectID, project.Name AS projectName,phase.ID AS phaseID, phase.Name AS phaseName, tv.id as treeview_items_id FROM company left join project ON project.CompanyID = company.ID left join phase ON phase.ProjectID = project.ID left join treeview_items tv on(tv.text = phase.Name) WHERE company.Name = 'Company2' Order By project.ID

Comment: the exact result of the screen shot was given by the query in the answer. It is not clear what do you expect

Comment: That query I had try dy before, but it will provide duplicate record. It is because we use left join treeview_items tv on(tv.text = phase.Name). tv.text have two same text which is Phase1 when the company.Name = 'Company2'.